# Formula that creates a list based on cell value

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a list of employees that choose different insurance coverages in a workbook.  I am looking to make a formula that creates a list based on whether a cell has a value or not (column B).

Here is how my workbook looks:

[image]

I have tried the following formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,SMALL(IF(B2="<>""",ROW($A$2:$A$9)-(ROW($A$2)-1)),ROWS($1:1))),"")}
```

Here is the answer I am seeking:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: change `B2="<>"""` to `$B$2:$B$9<>""`

Comment: @ScottCraner - you are awesome, appreciate all of your help the last two days!